# Why does grouping my CollectionViewCells messes up my Segues (JSON)

Tags: ios, json

My app has a CollectionView (UpcomingReleasesViewController), and a CollectionViewCell (ReleaseCell). Each Cell has certain information (release_name and release_price), which I'm parsing from a Rails app with JSON.

Once you click on a Cell the app would take you to a detailed view (ReleaseViewController) showing that information. This is the code I first had which did what I wanted.

**UpcomingReleasesViewController.m**

```
@interface UpcomingReleasesViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *upcomingReleases;

@end

@implementation UpcomingReleasesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.upcomingReleases = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {
        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_price = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_price"];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        [self.upcomingReleases addObject:upcomingRelease];
    }

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ReleaseCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReleaseCell"];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    ReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.release_name.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;
    cell.release_price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", upcomingRelease.release_price];

   return cell;
} 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRelease"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        ReleaseViewController *releaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        releaseViewController.singleRelease = self.upcomingReleases[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

This is my detailedViewController (ReleaseViewController)

**ReleaseViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UpcomingRelease.h"

@interface ReleaseViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UpcomingRelease *singleRelease;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_price;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_date;

@end
```

**ReleaseViewController.h**

```
#import "ReleaseViewController.h"

@interface ReleaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReleaseViewController

@synthesize singleRelease = _singleRelease;
@synthesize release_name = _release_name;
@synthesize release_price = _release_price;
@synthesize release_date = _release_date;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.release_name.text = self.singleRelease.release_name;
    self.release_price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _singleRelease.release_price];
    self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _singleRelease.formattedDate];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Now I'm trying to "group" the Cells by their release date (a date-time string being parsed through JSON), and I got it to work, but the Segue is broken and whenever I click on a Cell the app takes me to a blank page (for some reason the release_name label is blank and the release_price label returns "nill").

**UpcomingReleasesViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *upReleases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *releaseBuckets;
```

**UpcomingReleasesViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    //This is the dateFormatter we'll need to parse the release dates

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSv"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]; //A bit of an overkill to avoid bugs on different locales

        //Temp array where we'll store the unsorted bucket dates
    NSMutableArray *buckets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {

        //We find the release date from the string
        NSDate *releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"]];

        //We create a new date that ignores everything that is not the actual day
        //(ignoring stuff like the time of the day)
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components =
        [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:releaseDate];

        //This will represent our releases "bucket"
        NSDate *bucket = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //We get the existing objects in the bucket and update it with the latest addition
        NSMutableArray *releasesInBucket = [tmpDict objectForKey:bucket];           
        if (!releasesInBucket){
            releasesInBucket = [NSMutableArray array];
            [buckets addObject:bucket];
        }

        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_price = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_price"];
        [releasesInBucket addObject:upcomingRelease];
        [tmpDict setObject:releasesInBucket forKey:bucket];
    }

    [buckets sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate* date1 = obj1;
        NSDate* date2 = obj2;
        //This will sort the dates in ascending order (earlier dates first)
        return [date1 compare:date2];       
        //Use [date2 compare:date1] if you want an descending order
    }];


    self.upReleases = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tmpDict];
    self.releaseBuckets = [NSArray arrayWithArray:buckets];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [self.releaseBuckets count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.upReleases objectForKey:self.releaseBuckets[section]] count];
}

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ReleasesGroup* releaseGroup = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"releasesGroup" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //We tell the formatter to produce a date in the format "Name-of-the-month day"
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];

    //We read the bucket date and feed it to the date formatter
    NSDate* bucketDate = self.releaseBuckets[indexPath.section];

    releaseGroup.releasesHeader.text = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:bucketDate] uppercaseString];
    return releaseGroup;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UpcomingReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upReleases objectForKey:self.releaseBuckets[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];

    cell.release_name.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Open Release Page

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRelease"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        ReleaseViewController *releaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        releaseViewController.singleRelease = self.upcomingReleases[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

What do I need to change so the Segue works properly again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your actual code, then your problem lies in the `prepareForSegue::` method. That's still your 'old' implementation, as far as I can see:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRelease"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        ReleaseViewController *releaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        releaseViewController.singleRelease = self.upcomingReleases[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

You can't get the correct object with only the indexPath's row. Just like in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, get it from your dictionary:

```
releaseViewController.singleRelease = [self.upReleases objectForKey:self.releaseBuckets[selectedIndexPath.section]][selectedIndexPath.row];
```